# ActionFilterAttribute for the controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

after having applied the very same action filter to all the actions of a controller, I wonder if there is a controller filter so that I can apply it to the class and avoid declaring it for every action.

I've tried to solve the problem applying the attribute to the controller constructor, but not being an action it fails to compile.

Answer (score 1):

you can apply directly to the class

```
namespace somenamespace.Controllers {
    [somenamespace.HelpersClass.ActionFilters.SomeControllerFilter]
    public  class SomeController : Controller {
    }
```